# Match everything until optional string (Python regex)

Tags: python, regex

I've pounded my head against this issue, and it just seems like I am missing something uber-trivial, so apologies in advance. I have a url, which may, or may not, contain some POST values. I want to match the the entire url UNTIL this optional part (not inclusive). So for example:

```
import re
myurl = r'http://myAddress.com/index.aspx?cat=ThisPartChanges&pageNum=41'
matchObj  =  re.match(r'(.*?)(&pageinfo=\d+){0,1}', myurl)
print matchObj.groups()
>> ('', None)

# Putting the non-greedy ? outside
matchObj  =  re.match(r'(.*)?(&pageinfo=\d+){0,1}', myurl)
print matchObj.groups()
>> ('http://myAddress.com/index.aspx?cat=ThisPartChanges&pageNum=41', None)

# The url might also be without the last part, that is
myurl = r'http://myAddress.com/index.aspx?cat=ThisPartChanges'
# I'd like the regex to capture the first part. "ThisPartChanges" might 
# be different every time
```

What I would like is to get the everything until pageNum=\d+, not inclusive.
That is

```
http://myAddress.com/index.aspx?cat=ThisPartChanges
```

I am only interested in the part before &pageNum, and don't care if it exists or not, just want to filter it out somehow so that I can get the real address until cat=....

I've tried all sorts of non-greedy acrobatics, but the part that fails me is that the 2nd part is optional, so there's nothing to 'anchor' the non-greedy match.
Any ideas how to elegantly do this? Only the first part is important. Non-regex solutions are also welcome

Thanks!

Comment: using urlparse is better for sure, but for your regex question it would be `re.match(r'^(.*)&pageNum=.*', myurl)`.

Comment: `(.*?)(&pageNum=\d+){0,1}` was _almost_ correct, you just need to add an end-of-string anchor: `(.*?)(&pageNum=\d+){0,1}$`.

Comment: Mon dieu! That is correct! How could I have missed that? :) :) (I feel slightly silly now, but thanks!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend you to avoid regular expressions when it comes to url parsing, use this [module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) instead, here's a working example for your problem:

```
import urlparse

myurl = 'http://myAddress.com/index.aspx?cat=ThisPartChanges&pageNum=41'

parsed = urlparse.urlparse(myurl)

print 'scheme  :', parsed.scheme
print 'netloc  :', parsed.netloc
print 'path    :', parsed.path
print 'params  :', parsed.params
print 'query   :', parsed.query
print 'fragment:', parsed.fragment
print 'username:', parsed.username
print 'password:', parsed.password
print 'hostname:', parsed.hostname, '(netloc in lower case)'
print 'port    :', parsed.port

print urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, I'll keep it in mind and use urlparse from hereon in

Comment: @Ruslan Look at this blog post to learn how to modify URLs using the urlparse module: http://www.daveoncode.com/2014/11/06/high-level-url-manipulation-using-native-python-api-urlparse-urllib/

Answer (score 3):

you may want to take a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html

the order in which parameters are passed may change:

```
?pageNum=41&cat=ThisPartChanges
```

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't familiar with that

Answer (score 1):

In your case, this could do:

```
^[^&]+
```

More robust:

```
^[^?]+\?cat=[^&]+
```

**Example:**

```
In [40]: s = 'http://myAddress.com/index.aspx?cat=ThisPartChanges&pageNum=41'

In [41]: re.search(r'^[^&]+', s).group()
Out[41]: 'http://myAddress.com/index.aspx?cat=ThisPartChanges'

In [42]: re.search(r'^[^?]+\?cat=[^&]+', s).group()
Out[42]: 'http://myAddress.com/index.aspx?cat=ThisPartChanges'
```

Comment: Thanks!! In this case I'll probably still use urlparse since it seems more robust, but thanks! This is a neat regex trick to keep in mind